# Object.prototype.values breaks application

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why `Object.prototype.values` breaks app in totally different place? Even if `values` changed to `myvalues`

```
Object.prototype.values = function (obj) {
    var vals = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
        return obj[key];
    });
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: Why would you add a method to the Object.prototype and then *not* use `this` within the method?

Comment: Its working fine. I just tested it out in my console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT change the native object prototype because this can break for-in loops without [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) filter and may have other side effects somewhere else in your app or used libraries.

Better change `Object.prototype.values` to `Object.values` and use it like `Object.keys`.